# Events between components not on the same system

Tags: apex, lightning-web-components, platform-event, lightning-events, lightning-message-service

As the question goes, what can I use to communicate between 2 LWC components which are accessed by different users?

I am trying to build a Sprint planning poker app in LWC, where the vote submitted by one user needs to by updated on the component on another users screen.

Using lightining messaging service does not work because unless the components are on the same page, the events wont propagate. Is using platform events the only way?

Comment: Platform events should be able to handle these scenarios well, is there any reason you need another approach?

Comment: Thanks @PrashantKashyap. I was just looking for a way to avoid the limits from SF by using platform events. I will try this method and revert back to you.